# Bindings not updated. Can't see what's wrong

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsuserdefaults, cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing

This is my setup:

In my app delegate, I register my defaults.

In my preferences nib I have bound a checkbox to the shared user defaults with controller key `values` and model key path `test`.

In my custom object I have a `property BOOL test` and in its `init` method I call

```
[self bind: @"test" toObject: [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] withKeyPath: @"values.test" options: nil];
```

In the same object I have the `@property NSString *testString` and I also have a `+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingTestString` which returns an NSSet with `@"test"`.

I subclassed `- (NSString *)testString` but it never gets called.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution: if I use `[NSUserDefaultsController sharedUserDefaultsController]` instead of `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` it works.

Comment: Yup. Remember that Bindings is part of AppKit, so you need one of AppKit's Bindings-aware objects, not a Foundation Bindings-unaware object. NSUDC is the former; NSUD is the latter.